# Splunk Client Module for multiple host

Tags: python, python-3.x, splunk

I am pretty new to Splunk and Python.

I am using Splunklib.client to connect the Splunk API. My code is below:

```
import splunklib.client as client
import splunklib.results as result
HOST = 'Localhost'
PORT = '8000
USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"

service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD)
rr = results.ResultsReader(service.jobs.export("query")
```

My questions is I have multiple host such as localhost1, localhost2,localhost3 etc, is there a way to get the data through this module on multiple host?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
service1 = client.connect(
    host=HOST1,
    port=PORT1,
    username=USERNAME1,
    password=PASSWORD1)
rr = results.ResultsReader(service1.jobs.export("query")

service2 = client.connect(
    host=HOST2,
    port=PORT2,
    username=USERNAME2,
    password=PASSWORD2)
rr = results.ResultsReader(service2.jobs.export("query")
```

Comment: Thank you Utah, I did think about solutions in this way, but I am not sure will I get the data separately or I can get the entire data from all the host.

Comment: I've not used the module you're talking about specifically, but unless the author uses static variables in a weird way, you will get them separately in this case.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you'll want to process `rr` before running the second one or assign the second's results to a different variable than `rr`.